# Padding too large when zoom in Files

Tags: files, filemanager, zooming

The space between images is too large when I zoom in to see them better in the file manager (Nautilus?):

[image: Zoom too big]

As you can see with my mad Gimp skills, you could easily fit 300% more content (5 instead of 2) if the margins were tighten for the same zoom level:

[image: Mad GIMP Skills]

**So, is there any way to reduce this separation between files?**

Comment: It's 250% not 300%